# How to check a value exist in a nested python dictionarie

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i want to check a value exist in my nested python dictionary.my dictionary is

```
dic = {'sample': {'a': 'hi', 'callback': 'foo'}}
```

I want to check the "callback" key of nested dictionary  is exist or not in this dic. The key 'sample' can vary so we can't check like dic['sample'] .There will be only one key in the outer dic

Comment: So, what exactly is the logic? Is there only one key in the outer dict? Or may there be multiple? Is it always exactly one key, or perhaps zero?

Comment: there will be only one key in the outer dic and the value will vary

Comment: `'callback' in next(iter(dic.values()))`…?

Comment: Perfect..That is working